# Jquery Mobile event "Pageshow", then add click event only works with refresh/reload Page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using JQM and I am trying to add an onclick event to every div, with the class Description, within a Page.

I know that i cant use just

```
$this.find(".Description").on("click", onButtonInfo_Click);
```

cause it's all ajax.

Thats way i tried this:

```
$this.find(".Description").on("click", onButtonInfo_Click);

$(document).on("pageshow", function () {
    $this.find(".Description").on("click", onButtonInfo_Click);
});
```

But this still not working because at the time when its triggered, i wont have the whole page in "$this" loaded. When i do a reload of the page all works fine.

Somone an Idea?

Markus

Answer (score 1):

Just add the click callback event directly.

```
$(document).on('click','.Description', function () {
 onButtonInfo_Click();
 //other code
});
```